# All the datas are not coming in pdf - JSPDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

I am using jspdf to convet html to pdf

Here, my page is more lengthy. it will be around 2 to 3 pages.

If i do convert, some contents are not coming. some are not in pdf

```
html2canvas(document.body).then(function(canvas) {
                background:'#fff',
                document.getElementById("cisForm").appendChild(canvas);
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                context.fillStyle="#FFFFFF";

                 l = {
                     orientation: 'p',
                     unit: 'pt',
                     format: 'a3',
                     compress: true,
                     fontSize: 8,
                     lineHeight: 1,
                     autoSize: false,
                     printHeaders: true
                 };

                var doc = new jsPDF(l, "", "", "");
                doc.addImage(canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"), 'jpeg', 0,0)
                window.location=doc.output("datauristring")
                //doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
            });
```

There is any settings for show all datas in pdf?

Answer (score 0):

Add `pagesplit:true` after background:'#fff'option in html2canvas method.This will add pages.